# Why are changes to my data obj not reflecting in vue.js template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am updating some live timers in my vue.js app.
I ran into an issue earlier where the changes to the timers were too deeply nested in my data object for vue.js to pick up on in the template.

So what I did is I restructured my data and started making shallow objects, structured like so:

```
testDict = {dynamicallygeneratedname: '5 minutes', anotherrandomname: '1 minute}
```

The values here get changed every second, and I can verify this is working by console.log(this.testDict) showing the updated times

from in my vue.template, I am calling `{{ testDict.anotherrandomname }}`, but the template will not update with the live time as shown in console.log

I'm at a loss for why this isn't working as I completely restructured my data into flat data sets specifically for reactivity.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

```
  data() {
    return {
      testDict: {},
    }
  },
```

Comment: Flat data sets are not required for reactivity as the reactivity system will walk nested objects and add reactivity recursively. An object needs to be in either the `data` of a component or the `state` of the store to become reactive in the first place (assuming you aren't using `Vue.observable` directly). Beyond that, there are caveats around the types of changes Vue can't detect: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats. From the code you've posted there isn't enough to work out what is wrong but in theory it should work if you've satisfied the conditions above.

Comment: testDict is defined in the data of this component

Comment: A complete example that we can actually run would be helpful. Currently we just have the line `testDict = ...`, which seems to be just assigning it to a local variable, not `this.testDict`. Even if you are assigning it to `this.testDict` your use of timers makes me wonder whether you've got a `this` scoping issue. Without a complete example I can only speculate.

Comment: I assume the issue is because I'm dynamically adding the key names to testDict, and vue's reactivity system doesnt support this I think.

Comment: Vue cannot detect the addition of new properties to objects. See the link I posted earlier for an explanation of how to solve this problem.